# Doctrine Record Listener never fired

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I'm trying to create **one record listener for all models**.

In ProjectConfiguration.class.php I added:

```
public function configureDoctrineConnection(Doctrine_Connection $connection)
{    
  $connection->addRecordListener(new doctrineLogger());    
}
```

And I created lib/doctrineLogger.class.php

```
class doctrineLogger implements Doctrine_Overloadable
{
  public function __call($m, $a)
  {
    echo 'caught event '. $m .'<br />';
  }
}
```

**But no event is ever caught.**

When I tried general connection listener with this:

```
$connection->addListener(new doctrineLogger());
```

... and the same doctrineLogger class, I got expected output properly:

```
caught event preConnect
caught event preExec
caught event postExec
caught event postConnect
caught event prePrepare
caught event postPrepare
...
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I implementing it incorrectly? Please help, I'm clueless. I'm trying to use Doctrine listeners for a first time.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're doing it wrong. Looking at the API-docs, it's not easy to spot though. The connection does indeed have an `addRecordListener`-method, inherited from `Doctrine_Configurable`. However, it is not usable for adding global record listeners on the connection level. Instead, you should add it to the `Doctrine_Manager`-instance:

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->addRecordListener(new doctrineLogger());
```

You can look at the reference documentation about [record listeners here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/event-listeners/en#record-listeners).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working. No change. And looking one more time into docs, actually it should be possible to add record listener to connection (Attaching the listener to a connection is as easy as: $conn->addRecordListener(new Debugger());). It doesn't matter to me whether it's on connection or manager. Strangely it's not working neither way.